# CSS Effect with After: Circle behind another circle

Tags: css

Reference:
http://tympanus.net/Development/IconHoverEffects/#set-7

When you rollover any of the circle icon in the link above, it fades in a CURVE (which I believe is another WHITE circle behind that circle which pops up). I don't want that rollover effect, but I want to have a simple curve near the circle.

I believe we can do it with the `css` `after` class. I tried to create a `.circle` class and put the `after` with increase of 10px margin, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone please check my code, or suggest how to achieve this ?

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dBQ5s/

CSS

```
.circle {
    background:#000;
    color:#FFF !important;
    text-align:center;
    -moz-border-radius:75px;
    -webkit-border-radius:75px;
    border-radius:75px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:5px SOLID RED;
}

.circle:after {
    background:green;
    -moz-border-radius:75px;
    -webkit-border-radius:75px;
    border-radius:75px;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That effect is being caused by a `box-shadow` and nothing more. :]

**They are** using pseudo elements on that page for the effect though!

**Important tip** make sure to include `content: "";` and, me personally, `display: block;` to pseudo elements in their css.

This is the css I added to achieve the effect,

```
.circle {
    background:#000;
    color:#FFF !important;
    text-align:center;
    -moz-border-radius:75px;
    -webkit-border-radius:75px;
    border-radius:75px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:5px SOLID #fff;
}

.circle:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 0 black;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dBQ5s/1/)

---

Here is how you would achieve the same animation and effect with pseudo elements,

```
.circle {
    background:#000;
    color:#FFF !important;
    text-align:center;
    -moz-border-radius:75px;
    -webkit-border-radius:75px;
    border-radius:75px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
}

.circle:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -55px;
    margin-top: -55px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 0 black;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

}

.circle:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

Fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dBQ5s/4/)

Comment: No problem! I am replicating the exact effect for ya so give me a sec. :]

Comment: @user1718343 I have included a new fiddle link/css to see how to achieve the animation as well.

Comment: Josh, you are amazing and expert :) thank you for the bonus.. I highly appreciate your help, I wish I had that much knowledge, I would have done this but in atleast 2 hours :) by reading and finding help.. great man.. thanks a LOT..

Comment: Haha thank you mate! I am always happy to help, best of luck on your project! A helpful tip when use pseudo elements, make sure this is always in the pseudo element's css, `content: "";` and I always add `display: block;` to the element as well.

Comment: Thanks once again Josh.. I tried to find "Add Friend" on stackoverflow :) but no luck.. lol

Comment: lol no problem mate. There is no "add friend" but I am always looking through `css` questions so I'm sure you'll see me around.